# Is there any difference between initializing variables in for loop (inside round brackets) and initializing variables before for loop?

Tags: c, pointers

Given a piece of code:

```
void twoDimFunc(int (*p)[HEIGHT])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (;i < WIDTH ; i++)
        for (;j < HEIGHT; j++)
        {
            *((int*)p + i * HEIGHT + j) =  -1;
        }

}
```

in main() program I call this function, and then output the matrix, and then I got the following matrix in stdout:

```
-1 -1 -1
0 0 0
```

However, for this code

```
void twoDimFunc(int (*p)[HEIGHT])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < WIDTH ; i++)
        for (j = 0;j < HEIGHT; j++)
        {
            *((int*)p + i * HEIGHT + j) =  -1;
        }

}
```

The output is

```
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

Does initialization inside for loop round brackets behave different way than initializing before for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't write obscure for loops when you can write readable (and therefore bug-free) ones `for(int i=0; i<WIDTH; i++) for(int j=0; j<HEIGHT; j++)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This two codes have a different behavior. In this code :

```
void twoDimFunc(int (*p)[HEIGHT])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < WIDTH ; i++) //loop 1
        for (j = 0;j < HEIGHT; j++) //j = 0 at each turn of loop 1
        {
            *((int*)p + i * HEIGHT + j) =  -1;
        }

}
```

`j` is never reinitialized at 0 in the first code you gave:

```
void twoDimFunc(int (*p)[HEIGHT])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (;i < WIDTH ; i++) //loop 1
        for (;j < HEIGHT; j++) //j isn't initialized to 0 for each turn of loop 1
        {
            *((int*)p + i * HEIGHT + j) =  -1;
        }

}
```

Comment: Yeah :) I'm just tired :)

Comment: No problem, it happens ! ^^

Comment: Can't accept your answer, stack overflow says "An error has occurred - please retry your request."

Answer (score 0):

Initializing before the loop and inside the parenthesis makes no semantic difference (maybe it makes a difference for the optimizer, who knows...).

But in your first nested loops, you don't reinitialize `j` every time so that the inner loop is never more executed.